# Get a random number through Chainlink VRF v2., but it has been pending, and it has been pending for two days

Tags: random, numbers, solidity, chainlink

Obtain a random number through Chainlink VRF v2. But it has been pending, and it has been pending for two days. My link balance is enough, but it just can't be successful.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUxTw.png)

Answer (score 2):

Chainlink VRF v2 has some [subscription limits](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/introduction/#subscription-limits)

Each subscription must maintain a minimum balance, or your requests remain pending for up to 24 hours before they expire.

> You can estimate the required minimum LINK balance using the following formula where max verification gas is always 200,000.
>
> `(((Gas lane maximum * (Max verification gas + Callback gas limit)) / (1,000,000,000 Gwei/ETH)) / (ETH/LINK price)) + LINK premium = Minimum LINK`

It seems that your LINK balance doesn't meet the minimum requirement.

Comment: thank you for this clue!!! adding 7 links worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

the requests are pending because your subscription is underfunded. Approximately 12 LINK is required for these two requests. Update the subscription balance, then if you let me know I'll get the transactions replayed

Comment: Why need about 12 LINK, not about 0.3 per transaction

Comment: Or how to see it is 12 LINK, thanks.

Comment: the amount of LINK required depends on the current gas price, your callback gas limit chosen, as well as the verification gas. Then the total amount in gwei is converted to LINK and then the node premium is added (0.005 for BNB Chain I think). https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/#subscription-billing. Do your requests have a lot of random numbers requested?

Comment: I only get a random number for one request.
I re-issued a contract with the same code, added a consumer, and then re-requested, there is no problem, I can get the random number in a very short time, I wonder if the chain card has been stuck before.

Comment: adding 7 links worked for me.